# How to use filter on google sheets API to showing data value in ASC?

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

i try to sort data on google sheet using google sheets api, example data like this table :

| name | day | sub |
| --- | --- | --- |
| teo | sun | 2 |
| deo | mon | 5 |

how to short table by name asc and get return value data using google sheet API?
i try like

```
public function GetUpdateValue()
    {
        $data = [
            'requests' => [
                [
                    'addFilterView' => [
                        'filter' => [
                            'filterViewId' => 0,
                            'title' => 'name',
                            'sortSpecs' => [
                                'dimensionIndex' => 1,
                                'sortOrder' => 'ASCENDING'
                            ],
                            'criteria' => [
                                '1' => [
                                    'condition' => [
                                        'type' => 'TEXT_EQ',
                                        'values' => [
                                            [
                                                'userEnteredValue' => 'name'
                                            ]
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ],
                    ],
                ]
            ]
        ];

        $service = new \Google_Service_Sheets($this->ClientAuth());
        $requestBody = new \Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateValuesRequest($data);

        $response = $service->spreadsheets_values->batchUpdate($this->spreadsheetID, $requestBody);

    }
```

its "right" obj / parameter that i need to input on $requestBody?

it used addFilterView or setBasicFilter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, you can use either "addFilterView" or "setBasicFilter". this is example for using "setBasicFilter".

```
$query = [
        'requests' => [
            [
                'setBasicFilter' => [
                    'filter' => [
                        'range' => [
                            'sheetId' => 0,
                            'startColumnIndex' => 0,
                            'endColumnIndex' => 3,
                            'startRowIndex' => 0
                        ],
                        'sortSpecs' => [
                            [
                                'dimensionIndex' => 0,
                                'sortOrder' => 'ASCENDING'
                            ]
                        ],
                        'filterSpecs' => [
                            [
                                'columnIndex' => 0,
                                'filterCriteria' => [
                                    'condition' => [
                                        'type' => 'TEXT_CONTAINS',
                                        'values' => [
                                            [
                                                'userEnteredValue' => 'deo'
                                            ]
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

you can use `sortSpecs` to filter asc or disc. Than you can use `filterSpecs` to filter with specific input by user or other.